# Running subprocess.call causes error

Tags: python, shell

I am getting following error while running subprocess.call() function.

```
error: must set personality to get -x option
```

I have shell script test.sh as below

```
#!/bin/bash
$1 >  $2
```

Below is my python code

```
action_path = '/home/test.sh'
val1 = 'ps -ax | grep python'
val2 = '/home/cvg/cvg.log'
retval=subprocess.call([action_path,val1,val2])
```

I am expecting the output of the command `'ps -ax | grep python'` should be logged to file mentioned. But I am getting the file as blank and 
error as mentioned at starting. Though I am able run this command succssfully on the terminal which output list of python processes running. 
I do not have any clue regarding this.
Please let me know if anybody knows about it.

Comment: I'd suggest reading [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), describing why commands stored in variables don't behave the way you expect.

Comment: @mannu_don, do you want to know how to best redirect output from an arbitrary shell command to a file with `subprocess.call()`? What's your real goal here? (If that *is* what you want, `subprocess.call('ps -ax | grep python', shell=True, stdout=open('/home/cvg/cvg.log', 'w'))` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside -- `grep`ping through `ps` is bad form; in general, you shouldn't do it at all, and if you *do* want to do it from Python, [the `psutil` module](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) will do the work for you.

The heart of this issue is [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Unquoted expansions like `$1` (for very good, security-related reasons) don't go through the full range of shell parsing steps -- quotes, redirections, pipes, command substitutions, and other syntactical elements are generally not recognized; only string-splitting and glob expansion take place.

---

*Also note that all of the below requires you to fix your `ps` command such that it actually works when run on your local platform -- a correction out-of-scope for a Python-focused question, particularly one not tagged with a specific operating system so we can look up its `ps` command's usage.*

#### Fixing Your Python

There's no reason for an intermediate shell script *at all*. Have your Python code open the output file directly.

```
subprocess.call('ps -ax | grep python', shell=True, stdout=open('/home/cvg/cvg.log', 'w'))
```

...or, if you *really* want your output file to be opened by a shell:

```
subprocess.call(['ps -ax | grep python >"$1"', '_', '/home/cvg/cvg.log'], shell=True)
```

Note that when `subprocess.call()` is passed a list, the first list element is the script to run; the second is `$0`, the third is `$1`, etc; hence, the `_` is a placeholder for `$0`, and the filename becomes `$1` in the context of the script.

#### Fixing This From Your Shell Script

You can have the interpreter evaluate the redirection internally:

```
#!/bin/sh
eval "$1" >"$2"
```

or, with even more inefficiency, have it start a new shell after the redirection itself (but why not have Python do that?):

```
#!/bin/sh
sh -c "$1" >"$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ps -ax` with `ps -ef`.

From `$ man ps`:

> To see every process on the system using standard syntax:
>
> ```
> ps -e        
> ps -ef
> ps -eF
> ps -ely
> ```

Comment: This isn't sufficient to resolve the issue -- the OP's code will be equivalent to running `'ps' '-ax' '|' 'grep' 'python'`; changing that to `-ef` doesn't fix the larger issue with the `|` being treated as literal rather than syntactic.